# solarized coloring only *fully* working in .vimrc file, other files have syntax coloring issues

Tags: vim

My .vimrc file contains :

```
syntax on
set background=light
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
se t_Co=16
colorscheme solarized
```

- I have put the solarized.clr file into my ~/Library/Colors/ folder

So this is some code in my .vimrc file :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByQ9h.png

This is some code in a test file within ~/ : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4vRD.png

I've been working on this for a while now.. driving me nuts. I'm new to all of this vim configuration stuff though.

Comment: You need `filetype plugin indent on` to enable filetype detection/indentation functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks as you haven't installed the solarized colors in your terminal emulator (for example, the background should be the same color as the background of [solarized's homepage](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), not white). The vim solarized color scheme [works only](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) if you set your terminal emulator to use the solarized colors. So it isn't actually fully working for any file.

Is your terminal emulator the Mac OS X Terminal.App? In this case, follow [these instructions](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/c350650cb74eed91895272d4b9d0fde8a335d223/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) (otherwise look for instructions for your terminal emulator on the scholarized homepage and in the [git repository](https://github.com/altercation/solarized)).

Comment: Is the Terminal.App the standard Terminal application that ships with OS X? If so, that is likely my problem. I'm going to give those instructions a try and will follow up with my results.