# Vim Solarized Color scheme: Should I have to set `call pathogen#infect()` in my .vimrc to make the syntax highlighting work properly?

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme

I'm new to vim and was wondering if I was supposed to have the `call pathogen#infect` in my .vimrc file.  If I don't have this it tells me `E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized`. I realize there are many questions out there on this topic but this one in specific I found difficult to answer.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

#### Details:

- Mac OSX
- iTerm
- ZSH (don't think this matters but thought I'd throw it in there.)

#### Also is this how the color scheme should look outside of files?

[image]

#### Articles referenced:

[Vim highlighting with solarized color scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838070/vim-highlighting-with-solarized-color-scheme)

[E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804767/e185-cannot-find-color-scheme-solarized)

[solarized coloring only *fully* working in .vimrc file, other files have syntax coloring issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784594/solarized-coloring-only-fully-working-in-vimrc-file-other-files-have-syntax)

[E10 errors in .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370730/e10-errors-in-vimrc)

[Adjust colors in vimrc or rather in the color scheme itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730204/adjust-colors-in-vimrc-or-rather-in-the-color-scheme-itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you installed Solarized. If it sits beneath `~/.vim/bundle` then yes, you need to `call pathogen#infect()`. (No package under there will be available otherwise.)

Your screenshot looks exactly like mine, although I never considered the possibility that I might be getting the wrong colours.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if the yellow was right.  But otherwise then I guess I'm all good! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Most welcome. Let me point out that you could also upvote or accept my answer if you found it helpful.